# 'Not feeling clever' - how far does this extend?

Tags: meaning, idioms, slang

The other day, when my wife was unwell, I happened to mention to a relative in Norfolk that she wasn't 'feeling too clever'. He instantly knew what I meant.

But it made me wonder how far this idiom extends. I'm sure I have heard it used in other parts of Britain, but is it universal throughout the Anglosphere?

Comment: Here in the U.S., it's unknown as an idiom. If you used it like that, we might interpret to mean your wife had just some something silly (or dumb) and then had recognized her error. Something akin to the modern *facepalm*. I don't expect the Canadians to know it either. But maybe the Aussies and Kiwis do?

Comment: Is it really an idiom? Dictionaries give it as a synonym of 'well' or 'healthy' in negative.

Oxford Dictionary: 
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clever
 item 2 [PREDICATIVE, WITH NEGATIVE] British informal Healthy or well

Comment: @javaNoobs "Not feeling that clever", while I've never encountered it myself (as I said), has shades of an idiom to me. You're right that the single word "*clever*", itself, is probably better categorized as slang or dialect or argot or what-have-you (that's what your ODO entry means by "British informal"), but I'm wondering if the four-word phrase "[not] feeling too clever", as a whole, is used often enough to qualify as an idiom (meaning: one whose form is set, not one whose meaning is un-derivable from the meanings of its constituent words).

Comment: Lovely expression, it sounds quintessentially British. I wonder how it came about, surely a play on *well* and its different meanings: to be in good health, and to do something competently (with intelligence).

Comment: @DanBron That is how it is mostly used i.e. *I'm not feeling too clever*; or often *my stomach doesn't feel too clever*.

Comment: Not known in New Zealand with that meaning.  I'd have interpreted it literally, as meaning that your wife felt less intellectually capable than usual, not necessary due to illness.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I wouldn't mind betting that many of your older generation would have used it. There is a specific reference to Australia and New Zealand in an OED entry on it, from 1937. See my comment below Edwin's answer.

Comment: I think you're the best person to answer this question [What is the etymology of “You don't look too clever”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/250553/what-is-the-etymology-of-you-dont-look-too-clever)

Comment: Apparently frequently used in the North East of England (Geordies primarily) for not feeling physically well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly still used here near Manchester (but less than was once the case).

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clever) give the sense, labelling it as an informal British usage:

> **clever** 2 [PREDICATIVE, WITH NEGATIVE] British informal
>
> Healthy or well:
>
> *I was up and about by this time though still not too clever.*

Comment: So, it's not an idiom. Just rare usage in some locations.

Comment: To my amazement I found it in the OED - meaning 4b. 
*‘Active’ as opposed to ‘infirm’; having ordinary healthy activity; in health, well. dial. Examples from 1746.

1815   Massachusetts Spy 14 June   I somehow did not feel quite clever, but hoped for the best.

1887   W. D. Parish & W. F. Shaw Dict. Kentish Dial.   Clever, in good health. ‘How are you to-day?’ ‘Well, thankee, not very clever’, i.e. not very active; not up to much exertion.

1937   E. Partridge Dict. Slang 158/2   Not too clever, indisposed in health..is common in Australia and New Zealand.*

Comment: I'd interpret your statement as meaning you still had a bit of "morning fog on the brain" - not thinking clearly yet, rather than not feeling healthy or well.  Of course with context I'd realize that "up and about" referred to out of bed after an illness rather than out of bed in the early morning.

Comment: It's ODO's example, which they interpret as matching their definition. Not mine (though it's the only way I've heard it being used). Can you find an authority saying it's used on your side of the pond?

Comment: @ javaNoobs The inclusion of a broadened sense in a dictionary does not necessarily mean that everyone would agree that what was once an idiom has now become a literal usage. Is 'a heavy smoker' idiomatic?