# What is the etymology of "You don't look too clever"

Tags: etymology, idioms

In BrEng, at least in the North, there is an idiom:

> "You don't look too clever."

which means

> "You're looking quite ill."

Does anybody know the etymology of this idiom please?

Comment: I'm not aware of those being "idioms" in the strictest sense of the word. They seem like normal sentence constructions to me: *You don't seem very bright* = *You don't look very intelligent* = *You're not exactly what I would call the [sharpest tool in the shed*](http://www.knowyourphrase.com/phrase-meanings/Not-the-Sharpest-Tool-in-Shed.html). The last one is an idiom.

Comment: I think you might have read the question wrongly. You don't have the meaning correct. It's used to describe somebody who looks unwell. It's nothing to do with intelligence.

Comment: Ops, sorry I just read the first and second lines without realizing that the second is the "translation" of the first.

Comment: related: [**'Not feeling clever'** - how far does this extend?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244092/not-feeling-clever-how-far-does-this-extend)

Comment: Perhaps @WS2 could answer the etymology question for you....

Comment: Is it _too clever_ as in the title, or _so clever_ as in the question?

Comment: Either is valid, however I've edited for consistency

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for making the link to my question. I have answered below.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't give the origin, but it is recognised by the OED as sense 5b of *clever*. see below. It is certainly well understood and used in Norfolk, and I feel sure I have heard Londoners use it.

> 5b. ‘Active’ as opposed to ‘infirm’; having ordinary healthy activity;
>   in health, well. dial.
>
> ?1746   ‘T. Bobbin’ View Lancs. Dial. Gloss.,   Clever, skilful, very
>   well.
>
> 1775   in Essex Inst. Hist. Coll. (1877) XIII. 196   Father was very
>   clever last Saturday p.m.
>
> 1815   Massachusetts Spy 14 June   I somehow did not feel quite
>   clever, but hoped for the best.
>
> 1887   W. D. Parish & W. F. Shaw Dict. Kentish Dial.   Clever, in good
>   health. ‘How are you to-day?’ ‘Well, thankee, not very clever’, i.e.
>   not very active; not up to much exertion.
>
> 1937   E. Partridge Dict. Slang 158/2   Not too clever, indisposed in
>   health..is common in Australia and New Zealand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've not been able to find the origin either. Hence this question.

Comment: It would not be idiomatic in most of the US, but would be readily understood, if the context were not too ambiguous.  (It could also mean you just made a fool of yourself, in a different context.)